# Docker Swarm - Unable to connect to other containers because IP lookup fails

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Say we provision an overlay network using docker swarm and create various containers with following names:

- Alice
- Bob
- Larry
- John

now if we try to ping any container from another it fails because it does not know how to do the IP lookup i.e., alice does not know bob's IP and so on. We have been taking care of this by manually editing the `/etc/hosts` on every container and entering the name/IP key value pair in that file but this is becoming very tedious with every restart of our network. There ought to be a better way of handling this.

E.g., services created using docker stack do not suffer from this problem. Due to various reasons we are stuck with creating containers using the vanilla `docker create`. How can we make containers discover each other on the overlay network without manual labor of editing `/etc/hosts`?

Below is detailed workflow we currently have to follow:

- we first provision a `docker swarm` and overlay network
- Then for each container, we create it using the `docker create` command and then start it using `docker start` command. we use the `--network` flag to attach the container to the overlay network at time of creation
- We then use `docker container inspect` to get the IP address of each container. This involves running `n` commands and noting down IP address.
- Then we log into each container and edit the `/etc/hosts` file by hand and enter the (name, IP) key-value pair of the other containers. So this means having to enter `n*(n-1)` records by hand when summed across containers.

Not sure why `docker create` does not do all this automatically - docker already knows (or can know) all the IP addresses. Containers provisioned using docker stack e.g., do not have to go through this manual process to "discover" each other. The reason why we cannot use docker stack is because:

- it does not allow us to specify container name
- we run various commands (mostly `docker cp`) before starting the container and not possible to do this using stack

Comment: related: https://blog.codeship.com/using-the-add-host-flag-for-dns-mapping-within-docker-containers/

Answer (score 0):

You might have seen this already: [DNS on User defines networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)

Have you created your services like in the section „Attach a service to an overlay“ in [this doc?](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/swarm/networking/)

Comment: The thing is that we are not creating services. We are creating containers. Maybe we need to start creating services but the reason we can't is because we need to docker cp some files to the container and services does not provide a way to do so. And we don't want to mount volumes.

Comment: Then perhaps try out cytopia/docker-bind (https://github.com/cytopia/docker-bind) or set up a dns server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only thing that is needed is to refer the containers by their `{name}.{network}` instead of just the `{name}`. No need to edit `/etc/hosts` or use the `--add-host` flag or run some additional dns server. Refer https://forums.docker.com/t/need-help-connecting-containers-in-swarm-mode/77944/6

Further details: the official documentation for docker does not mention anywhere the necessity to add `.{network}` suffix to the `{containername}`. Indeed on [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/#use-an-overlay-network-for-standalone-containers) link, Step #7 under the Walk-through, there is no `.{network}` suffix used. So not sure why we need to do that. The version of docker we are using is `18.06.1-ce` for linux.

Comment: Updating this thread: Now I don't even need the {network} suffix and the problem in the question does not repro any longer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue : I'm following this [official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/#use-an-overlay-network-for-standalone-containers) to create a docker swarm overlay network on two Raspberry pi 3 and the ping was impossible unless I found on [Github](https://github.com/dperson/openvpn-client/issues/365) the answer : as I understood, it seems that latest version of alpine (for a reason that I ignore) is not suitable for Raspberry pi 3 so the solution would be the use of the version 3.12.3 like this : `sudo docker run -dit --name alpine1 --network test1 alpine:3.12.3`

Hope that this might help someone :)